# Why isn't Anaconda for Windows Installing Properly?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, antivirus, pythonw

`Anaconda` 2 and 3 are installing without errors. I reboot because the installer prompts me to do so. When I open the `Anaconda Prompt`, `python`, `pythonw` or `activate.bat` aren't found. Looking in the `Anaconda[2|3]` folder, I can't find expected `.exe` and `.bat` files. What's going wrong?

I also notice that `conda update --all` wants to update many libs and eventually errors out.

Comment: Are you trying to install both Anaconda 2 and Anaconda 3? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anaconda installs and updates can silently fail due to conflicts with 3rd party antivirus (for me it's `WebRoot`) programs. An indicator of Anaconda antivirus conflicts is missing `.exe` and `.bat` files, and sometimes requests to reboot. The fix is to shutdown the antivirus program and reinstall `Anaconda`. I suspect Anaconda isn't following correct Windows installer procedures as it's the only installer than conflicts with WebRoot.

Answer (score 2):

INSTALL IT IN A EXTERNAL DISK!
I had a hard time tryig to install anaconda, because it was never complete, always missing anaconda navigator and the prompt. And after a cicle of install/unistall adopting different approaches, the only thing that made anaconda finally work properly in my computer was installing it in a exterior disk (or a pen drive).It just solved my problems, so give it a try!

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 3 years old) that already has an accepted answer (this is the case here) please ask yourself: Do you really have a substantial improvement to offer. If not, don’t answer.

Comment: I, for one, did find his comment useful, as I'm not using any 3rd party antivirus software, so the accepted answer is not relevant to my case.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from : https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/732#issuecomment-

1. ****** UNINSTALL ALL PYTHON INSTALLATIONS, OTHERWISE THEY WILL GET MESSED UP AND YOU CANNOT CLEANLY UNINSTALL THEM WITHOUT WINDOWS RESTORE, or at least I think these two problems were related *****

   2. Install Miniconda
   3. As Admin open CMD and change to directory where Miniconda is installed
   4. pythonw.exe -E -s "Lib_nsis.py" addpath
   5. pythonw.exe -E -s "Lib_nsis.py" mkdirs
   6. pythonw.exe -E -s "Lib_nsis.py" mkmenus
   7. run conda init to start the environment. Then exit that CMD
   8. I then ran Anaconda prompt from start menu, but you likely can use CMD
      note) if you run "conda list", you will see no packages installed, but good news is conda will install pacakges, so:
   9. conda install numpy
      note) this will install conda! lol
   10. conda install anaconda